# How to grep particular lines

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, wget

I am trying to fetch Some IDs from URL.

In my script I hit the URL using while loop and wget command and I save output in file.

Then in same loop I grep `XYZ User ID:` and 3 lines after this string and save it to another file.

When I open this output file I find following lines.

```
< p >XYZ User ID:< /p>

< /td >

< td>

< p>2989288174< /p>
```

So using `grep` or any thing else how can I print following output

```
XYZ User ID:2989288174
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (`sed` with extended regex):

```
sed -nr 's#<\s*p\s*>([^>]*)<\s*/\s*p\s*>#\1#p' file | tr -d '\n'
```

Output:

```
XYZ User ID:2989288174
```

Answer (score 3):

Supposing a constant `tag` pattern:

```
<p>XYZ User ID:</p>
</td>
<td>
<p>2989288174</p>
```

`grep` should be the best way:

```
grep -oP '(?<=p>)([^>]+?)(?=<\/p)' outputfile|while read user;do
  read id
  echo "$user $id"
done
```

Note that *look-behind* expressions cannot be of variable length. That means you cannot use quantifiers `?`, `*`, `+` , etc or alternation of different-length items inside them.

For variable length tags `awk` could be well suited for oneliner tags:

```
awk '/User ID/{print ""}/p *>/{printf $3}' FS='(p *>|<)' outputfile
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but still it's not the required output.

It gives following output after running command given by you.

XYZ User ID:
69687111

XYZ User ID:
188364506


However I require following output.

XYZ User ID: 69687111

Comment: Try the ``awk`` solution i just posted

Comment: I didn't notice that you want to group the results @innervoice